# avoid using java streams- android

Tags: java, android, stream

I have a code but I want to avoid using java streams because streams are not supported in android. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class VogelsApproximationMethod {

    final static int[] demand = {30, 20, 70, 30, 60};
    final static int[] supply = {50, 60, 50, 50};
    final static int[][] costs = {{16, 16, 13, 22, 17}, {14, 14, 13, 19, 15},
    {19, 19, 20, 23, 50}, {50, 12, 50, 15, 11}};

    final static int nRows = supply.length;
    final static int nCols = demand.length;

    static boolean[] rowDone = new boolean[nRows];
    static boolean[] colDone = new boolean[nCols];
    static int[][] result = new int[nRows][nCols];

    static ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int supplyLeft = stream(supply).sum();
        int totalCost = 0;

        while (supplyLeft > 0) {
            int[] cell = nextCell();
            int r = cell[0];
            int c = cell[1];

            int quantity = Math.min(demand[c], supply[r]);
            demand[c] -= quantity;
            if (demand[c] == 0)
                colDone[c] = true;

            supply[r] -= quantity;
            if (supply[r] == 0)
                rowDone[r] = true;

            result[r][c] = quantity;
            supplyLeft -= quantity;

            totalCost += quantity * costs[r][c];
        }

        stream(result).forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
        System.out.println("Total cost: " + totalCost);

        es.shutdown();
    }
```

i would be grateful if anyone can help me with this because i can't understand how stream works.

Comment: Just use a `for` loop to iterate over the first array dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is quite easy, you can use for loop as *Mike M* suggested in his comment see examples below:

```
int supplyLeft = 0;
int[] supply = {50, 60, 50, 50};
for (int i : supply) {
    supplyLeft += i;
}
System.out.println(supplyLeft);
```

to replace

```
int supplyLeft = stream(supply).sum();
```

if you don't want foreach either then

```
int supplyLeft = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < supply.length; i++) {
    supplyLeft += supply[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

As far as iterating through 2D array and replacing the java-8 stream as shown below is concerned

```
stream(result).forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

you can use a `for loop` or `Arrays.deepToString()` as per your needs see below example:

```
//assume your array is below, you can replace it with results everywhere
int[][] costs= { { 16, 16, 13, 22, 17 }, { 14, 14, 13, 19, 15 },
                { 19, 19, 20, 23, 50 }, { 50, 12, 50, 15, 11 } };

for (int i = 0; i < costs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(costs[i]));
}
```

Above `for loop` will print you the array in the following manner

```
[16, 16, 13, 22, 17]
[14, 14, 13, 19, 15]
[19, 19, 20, 23, 50]
[50, 12, 50, 15, 11]
```

If you use `Arrays.deepToString(costs)` then you get an output as shown below:

```
[[16, 16, 13, 22, 17], [14, 14, 13, 19, 15], [19, 19, 20, 23, 50], [50, 12, 50, 15, 11]]
```

Above to replace

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. what about the <<
        stream(result).forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));>>  is it enough to System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));??

Comment: You can use Arrays.deepToString(results) if you think that suffices your needs but, if you wish to print each row line by line then you can iterate through array using one for loop as I have shown above with costs array.